# setting contrast of image in PyQtGraph GraphicsWindow

Tags: image, pyqtgraph, contrast

I'm building a GUI and I want to allow the user to change the contrast of an image displayed through a PyQtGraph GraphicsWindow (say using a scroll bar or something). Any ideas?

My code looks something like this:

```
gw = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(OCT_WIDTH, OCT_HEIGHT), border=True)
gw_layout = gw.addLayout(row=0, col=0)
gw_view = gw_layout.addViewBox(row=1, col=0, lockAspect=True)
img = imread(imgPath)
imgItem = pg.ImageItem(img)
gw_view.addItem(imgItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` widget contains a color bar that can be used to modify the image contrast or intensity. See the ImageView [example](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/introduction.html#examples).

For convenience and future reference I copied the `ImageView.py` example here below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This example demonstrates the use of ImageView, which is a high-level widget for 
displaying and analyzing 2D and 3D data. ImageView provides:

  1. A zoomable region (ViewBox) for displaying the image
  2. A combination histogram and gradient editor (HistogramLUTItem) for
     controlling the visual appearance of the image
  3. A timeline for selecting the currently displayed frame (for 3D data only).
  4. Tools for very basic analysis of image data (see ROI and Norm buttons)

"""
## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)
import initExample

import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

# Interpret image data as row-major instead of col-major
pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with ImageView widget
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

## Create random 3D data set with noisy signals
img = pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 20 + 100
img = img[np.newaxis,:,:]
decay = np.exp(-np.linspace(0,0.3,100))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 200, 200))
data += img * decay
data += 2

## Add time-varying signal
sig = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
sig[30:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 70))
sig[40:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 60))
sig[70:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 30))

sig = sig[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * 3
data[:,50:60,30:40] += sig


## Display the data and assign each frame a time value from 1.0 to 3.0
imv.setImage(data, xvals=np.linspace(1., 3., data.shape[0]))

## Set a custom color map
colors = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (45, 5, 61),
    (84, 42, 55),
    (150, 87, 60),
    (208, 171, 141),
    (255, 255, 255)
]
cmap = pg.ColorMap(pos=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), color=colors)
imv.setColorMap(cmap)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```